# "bne" assembly command isn't doing what it should

Tags: assembly, 6502

I was trying to see if I could make a square wave tone generator on my 6502 cpu. After that I tried to make it change frequency over time but it always got stuck in a loop that counts the cycles of the output and changes the frequency after a speciffic amount of cycles. Here's the code:

```
PORTA = $6001
PORTB = $6000
DDRA = $6003
DDRB = $6002

TONE = $0200    ;1 byte
TEMPX = $0201   ;1 byte
TEMPY = $0202   ;1 byte
INDEX = $0203   ;3 bytes

CLEAR = %00000001

E = %10000000
RW = %01000000
RS = %00100000

 .org $c000
MUSIC:
T1:
 ldy #12
 ldx #75
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T2:
 ldy #8
 ldx #5
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T3:
 ldy #6
 ldx #37
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T4:
 ldy #5
 ldx #1
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T5:
 ldy #4
 ldx #25
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T6:
 ldy #3
 ldx #64
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T7:
 ldy #3
 ldx #18
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T8:
 ldy #2
 ldx #83
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
T9:
 ldy #2
 ldx #55
 jmp WAIT_LOOP
JH:
 jmp HLT

 .org $8000
RESET:               The programm starts here
 ldx #$ff
 txs

 cli

 lda #%11111111   ;setting port B as all output
 sta DDRB
 lda #%11100001   ;setting first 3 pins and last pin of port A as output
 sta DDRA

 lda #%00111000   ;initialize LCD in 8-bit mode, 5x8 font and 2 lines
 jsr LCD_INSTRUCTION
 lda #%00001110   ;initialize LCD to be on and have cursor on
 jsr LCD_INSTRUCTION
 lda #%00000110   ;set cursor move direction and set LCD to not scroll
 jsr LCD_INSTRUCTION

 jsr LCD_CLEAR

 lda #$4c
 sta INDEX
 lda #$00
 sta INDEX +1
 lda #$c0
 sta INDEX +2

 lda #%01010101
 sta TONE

 ldx #0
PRINT_MESSAGE:
 lda MESSAGE,x
 beq PLAY
 jsr PRINT_CHAR
 inx
 jmp PRINT_MESSAGE

PLAY:
 ldy #$ff
 ldx #$ff
PLAY_TONE:
 sty TEMPY
 stx TEMPX

 lda TONE
 and #%0000001
 sta PORTA

 lda TONE
 eor #$ff
 sta TONE

 jsr WAIT

 ldy TEMPY
 ldx TEMPX
 dex
 bne PLAY_TONE
 dey
 bne PLAY_TONE            it always gets stuck jumping to "PLAY_TONE"

INC_INDEX:
 clc
 lda INDEX +1
 adc #7
 sta INDEX +1
 lda INDEX +2
 adc #0
 sta INDEX +2

 jmp PLAY

HLT:
 jmp HLT

MESSAGE: .asciiz "Frequency: var                         Amplitude: 5V   "

WAIT:
 jmp INDEX
WAIT_LOOP:
 dex
 bne WAIT_LOOP
 dey
 bne WAIT_LOOP
 rts

LCD_WAIT:
 pha
 lda #%00000000   ;set port B as all input
 sta DDRB
LCD_BUSY:
 lda #RW
 sta PORTA
 lda #(RW|E)
 sta PORTA
 lda PORTB
 and #%10000000   ;only check busy flag
 bne LCD_BUSY

 lda #RW
 sta PORTA
 lda #%11111111   ;set port B back to all output
 sta DDRB
 pla
 rts

LCD_CLEAR:
 lda #CLEAR       ;clear LCD
 jsr LCD_INSTRUCTION

LCD_INSTRUCTION:
 jsr LCD_WAIT
 sta PORTB
 lda #%0          ;clear RS/RW/E bits
 sta PORTA
 lda #E           ;enable the LCD to send instruction
 sta PORTA
 lda #%0          ;clear RS/RW/E bits
 sta PORTA
 rts

PRINT_CHAR:
 jsr LCD_WAIT
 sta PORTB
 lda #RS         ;clear RW/E bits and switch RS on
 sta PORTA
 lda #(RS|E)     ;enable the LCD to send instruction
 sta PORTA
 lda #RS         ;clear RW/E bits and switch RS on
 sta PORTA
 rts

NMI:
 rti

BRK_IRQ:
 rti

EXIT_INT:
 rti

VECTORS:
 .org $fffa
 .word NMI
 .org $fffc
 .word RESET
 .org $fffe
 .word BRK_IRQ
```

I know that the code is probably horrably inefficient but i just want it to work
([I am using the setup from ben eater](https://eater.net/6502))
There is also an emulator of the setup I am using at https://www.tejotron.com/

After a certain amount of cycles the code should change frequency a few times and then stop by getting stuck in the loop "HLT". I have tried a few things but nothing worked.

Comment: There's a lot of code here (and several `bne` statements). Where specifically are you having problems? Is it possible to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, with an emphasis on "minimal"?

Comment: I'm suspicious of the `jmp INDEX`.  Are you sure you don't want `jmp (INDEX)`?  Also, the indirect `jmp` takes an address of a 2-byte value, not a 3-byte value, IIRC.  If that's bad, the loop you're citing with the `bne` may not resume.

Comment: `INDEX` contains a `JMP` instruction generated from code so that's okay.

Comment: Are you sure it's stuck and not just taking a long time? The first wait at `T1` takes about 20000 iterations and that is then multiplied by the 65536 loops. Should take well over half an hour. I assume you miscalculated some delay values. Try something smaller for the initial `TEMPY`.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you enter `WAITLOOP` `X` contains 75 and `Y` contains 12. It will count `X` 75 down to 0, then it will decrement Y to 11. Then it goes back to the top of the loop and decrements `X` (which contains zero at this point) from 0 to 0 (going the long way) and decrements `Y` again and do on until `Y` is zero.

So the first time through, you have 75 + 12 x 256 iterations of `WAITLOOP` and that is 3147 iterations. The code that does this takes 5 cycles for each `X` iteration plus a few more for each `Y` iteration. It's roughly 16,000 clock cycles.

In the loop that calls `WAITLOOP` you iterate 256 x 256 iterations. This is calling `WAITLOOP` 65,536 times. So in your first set of `PLAY_TONE` iterations, you spend around 1030,000,000 cycles just executing `WAITLOOP`. That's 1030 seconds or 17 minutes (assuming a 1MHz clock) not including all the other instructions in your loop.

I don't think it's stuck, I just think your loops are far too big.

---

**Side note**

In my opinion, your `JMP INDEX` is a little hincky. It kind of obfuscates what happens. If `INDEX` and `INDEX+1` just contain the address you want to jump to, you can just use the indirect form `JMP (INDEX)`. It will save you one clock cycle and one byte and also be more readable.

Comment: This program was an attempt of mine to get a square wave with variable frequency as an output. I made a prototype with a hardcoded frequency (x and y registers) and those values made a frequency well over 30 Hz. The problem I have with this wait loop is that after both values are 0 the “bne“ command that checks that Y is 0 does not work. I even tried an emulator that let me single step through the code and every time it gets to the end of the loop and resets for no apparent reason

Comment: @ThatRandomOctoling `DEY` will set the `Z` flag as appropriate. If your 6502 is not broken `DEY` followed by `BNE` will always follow the branch unless `Y` was 1 before the `DEY`.